# Combining woocommerce cart options if the same

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

So I've been working on an online store and I used the PPOM plugin for adding additional options for products.

Everything working great and they have an option to charge the extra option, if selected, only once also if the user added 3 of the same item.

But the problem starts when the user navigates to another product and adds the same option there too, in the cart the option is shown and charged once for each product.

I want to be able to catch all the options in the cart and check if they are equal and then combine/delete the extras and keep the option line only once (also charged once ofcorse).

[image]

Another solution that can work for me but haven't found how to do it is to put an option to choose if wanted by the user in the cart instead of in the individual products and then the user will select it only once in the cart itself. Any lead to this solution would also be great!

Any help in this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check with the plugin author to ask if there is a solution for this problem? Are you using the free or premium version of the plugin?

Comment: Hey @JamesRyvenValeii I'm using the free one and yes I spoke to them and they didn't have any legit answer, just "tell us what you need and we'll tell you the cost of the customization" response.

Comment: Gotcha. I am not certain about the path forward here - anything is possible, as you probably know. But this will probably be somewhat difficult. 

You can do per-product options with-fees and per-cart options with-fees with WPDesk software. I have used the premium versions of their software and was pleased. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-checkout-fields/

Comment: @JamesRyvenValeii Thanks! do you know if the pro version has also an option for a free gift if the cart reached a specific amount?